# How to call a remote table-value function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I created this query

```
select top 100 * 
from openquery(LIVSQL02,'select * from [LIVSQL02].[DFeed90].[dfeed].[FNTB_Change_Cargo]( 0, 10 )')
```

When I execute the system returns the error

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LIVSQL02" returned
>   message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.". Messaggio 8180,
>   livello 16, stato 1, riga 1 Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   Messaggio 4122, livello 16, stato 1, riga 1 Remote table-valued
>   function calls are not allowed.

Thanks

Comment: Your *remote* query should not additionally include the server name (`LIVSQL02`); this causes the inner query to fail, as `SELECT ... FROM server.db.scheme.function(...)` is not allowed. `SELECT ... FROM OPENQUERY(server, 'SELECT * FROM db.scheme.function(...)')` should work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you should put your comment in as an answer.